# Extracting a value from webpage element with selenium, fiebug, xpaths

Tags: html, ruby, xpath, cucumber, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to extract  a value displayed in an element(drop down box) on a webpage using xpaths. I have firebug and xpath checker installed in firefox and the element I am trying to extract from looks like such:

```
<input id="dateTxt" class="textBox" value="Thursday June 20" onfocus="this.blur()"   onclick="gird.show('date')" size="9" maxlength="50" readonly="readonly">
```

Apologies I am not allowed to share exactly what I'm working with but that is the jist.

I want to save the ontents of value ( value = "Thursday June 20" ) to a string so I can parse for the date. But I have not been able to get the xpath correct. This is what I have so far as in my code

```
text = @driver.find_element(:xpath => "//*[@id=\"dateTxt\"]")
```

If I perform .text on this nothing is assigned to text.

If more information is needed please request it, this is my first day working with xpaths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Humm.. You can try the below :

```
@driver.find_element(:css,"input#dateTxt").attribute("value")
#=> "Thursday June 20"

@driver.find_element(:xpath,"//input[@id = 'dateTxt']").attribute("value")
#=> "Thursday June 20"
```

Look at the below page [`Element examples:`](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings) and [`Selenium::WebDriver::Element#attribute`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/0.0.28/Selenium/WebDriver/Element#attribute-instance_method)

Comment: I believe this accessed the value!Thank you for this. I also wonder though how to do this with xpaths? I am trying to be uniform with my tests and i'm at a point where I don't know if I should go with xpaths or just the access methods provided by selenium? Any input is really appreciated!

Comment: @megaxelize use `#css` whenever possible. It looks always good. I am also giving the `xpath` expression also wait.

Comment: A quick question on terminology? When you say use :css what does that mean? I just have always associated it with designing the page layout not a form of search or accessing values in the html document.

Comment: @megaxelize Like `#xpath`, `#css` is also a searching tool in selenium to find element(s) from the webpage.It uses [`CSS Selector`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).